# How can I add spacing between tasks in PlainTask for Sublime3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text3 and PlainTasks. I have a TODO list and I'm wondering if it possible to add spacing (something like padding: 10px 0; if it was CSS) between tasks? It's annoying that they don't have any spacing between them by default... I know I can add separators, but I really want to have spacing by default. I checked the preferences and didn't find anything related to that.

I found some html template files in AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\PlainTasks , and I tried tweaking the inline CSS there, but nothing changed.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set this via the "Syntax specific settings":

1. Make sure you have a plaintasks file open
2. Go to *Preferences* → *Settings - More* → *Syntax Specific - User*
3. Add the following lines to the json settings file:

```json
"line_padding_bottom": 2,
"line_padding_top": 2,
```

This would set a padding of 2px on top and bottom.

---

Source: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=54

Comment: Thank for your answer, but this adds spacing between lines instead of tasks (paragraphs). So it doesn't work for my case, since I have tasks going to more than one line. Can't access the sublime forum atm to check the link you provided....

Comment: @Spiridon Ah, I see. Sorry, I don't know how to do that.